# How to make counter application with cumulative sum in react like every count output should be 1,3,6,10,15,21

Tags: reactjs

```
function update()
{

setCount(count+1)
}  
return (
<>
<div>{count}</div>
<button onClick ={()=>update()}>clicme  </button>
</>
)}
```

Blockquote" where i can change this"

export default Anjal;**strong text**

Comment: Just create a new variable to keep track of the increment and update it after every click as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 state variables for `count` and numeric series.

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);    // count
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);    // Will save numeric series
```

And whenever the `count` is changed, we will calculate the cumulative sum to be inserted at the end of the numeric series.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (count > 0)
      setList(prev => [...prev, (1+count) * count / 2]);
  }, [count]);
```

And your update function should be changed:

```
  function update() {
    setCount(prev => prev + 1);
  }
```

Rendering part:

```
<div>Count: {count}, List: {list.join(', ', list)}</div>
<button onClick={() => update()}>clicme  </button>
```

Comment: but in there i dont want to make output in form a list i want to update the single value output on every click

Comment: In that case, there is no need to use `list` state.  Please just change the rendering part by `<div>Count: {count}, Sum: {(1+count) * count / 2}</div>`

Comment: okk @Liki Crus Thanks for your concern

Comment: And if possible, could you reformat your code in your question? Now code is correctly not formatted and has a syntax error.